Unable to perform git commands on remote from within script
I have script I want to run upon merging a pull request in GitHub. The script is written in JavaScript using the ZX library.
The purpose of the script is to automatically determine the next version of a package to be published to npm and the actions including fetching the latest git tags from GitHub in order to negotiate what version to release under.
Unfortunately I'm struggling a lot with running a simple git pull --tags action. I managed to install act which enables me to run the script locally.
When the script reaches the step where it pulls from git it times out. The error message is not very clear, but I see something with "Username" so I suspect it is trying to authenticate with GitHub using password instead of personal access token:
| Username for 'https://github.com': /Users/work/projects/aves/node_modules/zx/build/core.cjs:245
|             const output = new ProcessOutput(
|                            ^
| 
| ProcessOutput [Error]: 
|     at /Users/work/projects/aves/scripts/prepublish.js:609:37
|     exit code: null
|     signal: SIGTERM
|     at EventEmitter.end (/Users/work/projects/aves/node_modules/zx/build/core.cjs:245:28)
|     at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:519:28)
|     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/work/projects/aves/node_modules/zx/build/vendor.cjs:20283:16)
|     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
|     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
|     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
|     at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
|     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:338:12) {
|   _code: null,
|   _signal: 'SIGTERM',
|   _stdout: '',
|   _stderr: '',
|   _combined: ''
| }
| 
| Node.js v20.15.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.

This is my workflow:
name: Publish Package to npmjs
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: ['closed']
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Setup Node.js and copy .npmrc file
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - name: Configure git for HTTPS
        run: |
          git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:
          git config --global url.https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
      - name: Fetch tags
        run: yarn && yarn zx ./scripts/prepublish.js --ci

Initially, instead of running prepublish.js on the last line I ran:
  run: git pull --tags

And it used to work for a short while until I made some change I don't remember and now it also fails if I pull directly from the workflow.
Inside prepublish.js I tried various things:

I've tried printing the GITHUB_TOKEN. It works.

I've tried calling git commands that don't require authenticating with the remote repo, such as git status and it works fine.

I tried running git config --list and printing the output. Interestingly I notice that the token is not included in the output. I'm not sure if there is some logic in github to remove sensitive tokens before printing, but I tried to remove the x-access-token line from the workflow and instead running it inside prepublish.js like so:
await $`git config --global url.https://x-access-token:${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/`;

Subsequently printing git config does include the token in the url, but calls to git push still fails with the same error and I can't think of any other steps to try at this point.


Here is what I currently have in prepublish.js
#!/usr/bin/env zx

const zx = require('zx');

const { $, spinner } = zx;

(async () => {
  await $`git config --global url.https://x-access-token:${process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/`;
  const { stdout: gitConfig } = await $`git config --list`;

  console.log({ gitConfig });

  const { stdout, stderr } = await $`git pull --tags`.timeout('2m');

  if (stderr) {
    console.error('stderr:', stderr);
  }

  console.log('stdout:', stdout);

  return;
})()


Not sure I understand "The purpose of the script is to automatically determine the next version of a package to be published to npm"? Isn't that what npm version major, npm verison minor, and npm version patch are for? You run those, push to main with --tags, then you run npm publish. Because the only "freedom" there is which of those three is getting bumped, and I don't see anything in your script that checks that (which means it's safe to assume you're violating semver atm, in which case just keep violating it but using the normal npm commands?)

Currently I have omitted that part of the script in order to focus on getting the git commands to work. I do use npm version to set the actual version, but it's a custom script that needs to determine if it is a patch, minor or major release`.

This feels like it could benefit from "not using a custom solution" and instead using the JS version of octokit so you can talk to github the "normal" way? (e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/scripting-with-the-rest-api-and-javascript, which even covers how to integrate with github actions)

You're right I could use Octokit to fetch metadata such as tags. But after running npm version I would still be stuck because I would not be able to run git push --tags to push my new version to the remote anyway.

As mentioned in the question above I experience the same problem if I try to run git commands directly in the github action rather in the javascript file. I have already written the complete script that runs on local environments, so I would prefer to re-use it. But I realize I might need a different approach for my Github Actions workflow, but nothing is going to work if I can't pull and push to git.

Right, but my point is that your script is using bare https username:password authentication instead of "proper" API authentication. The log you're showing has git telling you that you need to log in interactively because the URL in your custom script doesn't. Something you're not going to run into when you use the official API library.

Ok, I did not realise that was what the output meant, but it makes sense. But what is then the "normal" way to authenticate git commands (not API calls) in a Github Action workflow? I don't think I can use the Octokit to make a git push --tags command?

Ok, I had some progress. Instead of rewriting the URL I was able  to re-add the remote with token auth:
git remote remove origin
git remote add org https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<org>/<repo>.git
After this I was able to git pull --tags. Unfortunately I am not able to read the token from .env with ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} and I had to hardcode the token which is obviously not feasible. GITHUB_TOKEN is available in my javascript, though.

What do you mean with "I am not able to read the token from .env"? Guthub actions use your project's github secrets, it does not use .env files (see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions)

I'm testing the workflow locally using act and I added a .env file for this purpose. I found a solution. See below.

Ah., my apologoies, I missed the part where you were testing with act: from day one that's suffered from being "similar to" but not actually "the same as" real github actions.

I managed to find a solution myself.
First, I was referencing the environment variable for GITHUB_TOKEN wrong in the run section. Instead of ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} I needed to use ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}.
Second, instead of rewriting URLs I needed to re-add the remote with the correct URL format:
git remote remove origin
git remote add org https://<user>:${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/<organisation>/<repo>.git

So eventually my workflow ended up looking like this:
name: Publish Package to npmjs
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: ['closed']
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - name: Git checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Node.js and copy .npmrc file
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - name: Configure git for HTTPS
        run: |
          git remote remove origin
          git remote add org https://GITHUB_ACTIONS_BOT:${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/<org>/<repo>.git
      - name: Fetch tags
        run: yarn && yarn zx ./scripts/prepublish.js --ci


Within prepublish.js I'm now able to execute git commands:
...
const version = ...

await $`npm version ${version}`
await $`git push --tags`
...

